# Cordova opentok plugin fails after publishing to session

Tags: cordova, opentok

Our app is currently in production using a fork from [songz](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/cordova-plugin-opentok) version, and we are trying to move on and use the new version from [opentok labs](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok) but we are experimenting this error over and over again:

```
[ERROR] otk_session_private.cpp:3201 - Failed to send stream create message.
[ERROR] otk_session_private.cpp:3226 - add_publisher: Failed for session=0x135dfaca0 video_orientation=0
```

[image]

- Cordova: 8.0.0
- Xcode: 10.1 (10B61)
- iPad Pro - iOS 12.1

Any clue?

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please share more details such as reproduction steps and the Cordova OpenTok plugin version? Feel free to file an issue on the GitHub repo as well.